# Check if a key exists without getting all node data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase's Realtime Database with node and I find that the only way to check that a key exists is to return all the data

```json
{
  "salas" : {
    "sala01" : {
      "activa" : true,
      "fechaComienzo" : "2021-10-16 07:09:00Z",
      "fechaCreacion" : "2021-10-16 07:09:24Z",
      "nombre" : "test",
      "masInfo": {
        ...
      }
    },
    "sala02" : {
      "activa" : true,
      "fechaComienzo" : "2021-10-16 07:09:00Z",
      "fechaCreacion" : "2021-10-16 07:09:24Z",
      "nombre" : "test",
      "masInfo": {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```js
async function checkExists(_ref, key) {
    const q = query(_ref, ...[orderByKey(), equalTo(key)])
    const datos = await get(q);
    console.log('@info', q, datos);
    return datos.exists();
}

const _ref = ref(getDatabase())
checkExists(_ref, 'sala01')
```

With the above example, if I want to know if `sala01` exists, it brings me every node with its descendants.

I wonder if there is any other way to simply check if `sala01` exists without bringing me the entire node or if there is some trick to bring a node with a depth as if I have seen in the REST API documentation, [shallow](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#shallow)

Comment: Someone explain to me why they have put me a negative without any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of query is more complex than needed:

```
const q = query(_ref, ...[orderByKey(), equalTo(key)])
```

If you know the key of a node already, you don't need to use a query, but can access that key directly.

```
async function checkExists(_ref, key) {
    const ref = child(_ref, key)
    const datos = await get(ref);
    return datos.exists();
}
```

This won't read read the entire `/_ref` node, but *will* read the entire `/_ref/$key` node. There is no way to test for the existence of a path without reading that path.